# How to clone File objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file

How can I create a copy of `File` object retrieved from `<input type="file"/>` element?

I tried with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(file))`

but `JSON.stringify(file)` always evaluates to `"{}"`

Comment: *the same way as any other object* - not any other object but plain object. The reason is clear, JSON.stringify reads only own enumerable properties, this is documented. It's unclear which file you're talking about, but as for browser File, file objects may contain size information for starters which would be unreachable if they wouldn't be aware of file contents. You can create a new one with `new File` but it's unknown whether this would work. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update the question if you have specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: `new File([file], file.name)` works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`new File([blob], blob.name, { type: blob.type });`

Adding the type is important. The accepted answer missed the type.

Comment: Don't forget `lastModified`. See constructor arguments at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File . `new File([oldFile], oldFile.name, { type: oldFile.type, lastModified: oldFile.lastModified });`

Answer (score 5):

`new File([file], file.name, {type: file.type})` returns copy of `file` object

Answer (score -3):

Use this-

```
var newFileObject = {...file} OR Object.assign({}, ...file)
```

OR Use -

```
JSON.parse(file.toString())
```

Comment: Answers that start with 'try this' usually have to be posted as comments. If you're not sure the solution is helpful without OP trying it first, it's not an answer. In this case this obviously won't work, for the reasons mentioned in the comment above.