# Why is the JavaScript spread notation not working here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shallow-copy

I am learning React and have this simple problem I can't solve.

I created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropzone-sha256-5ngg7?file=/src/FileUpload.js)

Here in the image: the `file` is a key-value array like the image show.

[image]

After this code below has run:

```
return { ...file, md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() };
```

Then the result is that key value pairs are removed like this image show:

[image]

As you see the file now only contains `path` and `md5` and everything else is gone.

I know this got to do with maybe shallow copy principle but I have search for a solution but can't understand how to fix this.

```
const FilePicker = ({ setNewFileForValidation }) => {
    const readFileContents = async file => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = () => {
                resolve(fileReader.result);
            };
            fileReader.onerror = reject;
            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        });
    };
    const readAllFiles = async AllFiles => {
        const results = await Promise.all(
            AllFiles.map(async file => {
                const fileContents = await readFileContents(file);
                return { ...file, md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() };
            }),
        );
        console.log(results, 'resutls');
        return results;
    };

    function onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
        readAllFiles(acceptedFiles).then(result => {
            setNewFileForValidation(result);
        });
    }
    return <Dropzone onDrop={onDrop} />;
};
```

The `file` is coming from [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) and contains the result from the file picker. Maybe that is the reason this spread copy does not work?

Comment: Maybe File is some kind of a special object? Not every property of every object is enumerable. Could you avoid the problem by doing ```return (file.md5=SHA256(fileContents).toString(),file);``` ?

Comment: More on special properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @loop yes it works using `return (file.md5=SHA256(fileContents).toString(),file);` but then I mutate state I think, not sure

Comment: I'm not sure if `.map` can be used with `async/await`.

Comment: I created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropzone-sha256-5ngg7?file=/src/FileUpload.js)

Comment: Please provide data as text, not as a picture of text. Humans with visual impairments and search engine bots can't read your images.

Comment: A map with async will just return an array of promises which is handled just fine here, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File is a special object whose properties are not enumerable. Therefore the spread syntax is not working expectedly. You need to [clone the File object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579163/how-to-clone-file-objects-in-javascript) using the File constructor.

```
readAllFiles = async (AllFiles) => {
    const results = await Promise.all(
      AllFiles.map(async (file) => {
        const fileContents = await this.readFileContents(file);
        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        //return { ...file, md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() };
        file = new File([file], file.name, { type: file.type })
        file.md5 = SHA256(fileContents).toString();
        return file;
      })
    );
    console.log(results, "result");
    return results;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can turn map to a for.

```
readAllFiles = async (AllFiles) => {
  let results = [];
  for (let file of AllFiles) {
    const fileContents = await this.readFileContents(file);
    results.push({ file, md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() });
  }

  console.log(results, "result");
  return results;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` instead of spread syntax so instead of:

```
{ ...file, md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() };
```

use this:

```
Object.assign(file, { md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() });
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct in that object spread doesn't copy non-enumerable properties, but it isn't right about the fact that `File` has non-enumerable properties. The reason the File's properties aren't copied when you spread is for a different reason.

Objects can have *own* properties as well as properties on their prototype. For example, the object `{x: 1}` has `x` as an own property, and then methods such as `toString()` on its prototype. When you spread an object, only the own (enumerable) properties are copied to the newly created object. In the case of a `File` object, it has no own properties (ie: it looks like `{}`), and rather, all of its properties you see are maintained on the prototype (`[[Prototype]]`) of `file` (and on its prototype, etc.):

```js
const file = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(file)); // [] (nothing here, so nothing is spread to the new object)
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(file))); // ["name", "lastModified", "lastModifiedDate", "webkitRelativePath", "constructor"] (not copied with `...` as they're on the prototype)
```

As a result, you can either create a new file object using `new File()` and pass through the properties of your `file` object to the constructor and then add your new property to this object (as shown in [loop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67376121/5648954)), or, if you're fine with modifying the original `file` object, you can do as other answers suggest and instead modify the `file` object directly.