# How to convert JS File instance to plain object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a file input and a handler function for it. I need to convert each file to a plain object and give it a URL using `URL.createObjectURL` and then store them.

```js
const files = [];
const handleFileUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  for (const file of Array.from(e.target.files)) {
    const plain = {...file, url: URL.createObjectURL(file)};
    files.push(plain);
  }
}
```

However, this does not work. `plain` turns out to have only `url` property (e.g. `{url: 'blob:http://localhost:8080/5a574d7f-178d-44f4-accf-4be313ac098a'}`)

I've also tried:

```js
Object.assign(file, { url: URL.createObjectURL(file) }) // still File instance, but with url
```

```js
Object.assign({ url: URL.createObjectURL(file) }, file) // plain object with only url
```

I expect to have `files` array consisting of plain objects with `url` property and `File` properties. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Alright, initially I wanted to store the files in a Redux store, but it was complaining about non-serializable values. Now I realize this was not a great idea at all.

I need URLs to show previews of the uploaded images. Turns out I need the `Files` themselves to send them as formdata later.

Is there a better way of storing and manipulating uploaded images while conveniently sharing them across several components? Would using simple `useState` and passing state as props to child components be a good option?

Comment: Why eagerly create the object URL for each file? This duplicates the data in memory. Why create it at all? The data still exists within each file instance.

Comment: A File object has no _own_ properties, which is what gets copied to the newly created object when you use `...` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72603965/5648954) for more info). All of its properties are maintained on its prototype. As jsejcksn suggested, it might be a better idea to compute `url` when needed rather than in advance

Answer (score 1):

A File object is not a typical JS object type, it's a Blob, I don't think is has any properties, the only methods and properties that you can access through it are owned by it's Prototype (not by the File itself), and you cannot "copy" methods or properties of an object in that case.

Why not just store it in the array this way:

```
const files = [];
const handleFileUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  for (const file of Array.from(e.target.files)) {
    const plain = {file: file, url: URL.createObjectURL(file)};
    files.push(plain);
  }
}
```